# on the fly equivalency to concurrency

Tags: flycheck

Is `on the fly` equivalent to `concurrent`?  This is a simple question and although it might not standard quality, I ask it anyway.

Comment: In what context? How does the question relate to emacs?

Comment: Because emacs has on-the-fly tools such as `electric-indent-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "on-the-fly" is a colloquialism for "happens as needed". With modes like Flymake and Flycheck, on-the-fly means that syntax checking will occur as you are editing code in a buffer without you needing to invoke the syntax checker yourself.

These modes will typically start a new process in the background to collect syntax errors. These processes run asynchronously, meaning that they do not stop you from editing the buffer while they run. This is a form of concurrency.

Comment: Basically, one does not need to fire a command as the tools and operations are executed without direct interaction by the user.